# When does document.ready actually fire?

Tags: jquery

Let's consider the following case:

There is a 2.5MB image in an `<img>` tag and I'm on a slow connection which takes considerable time to download that image. If I'm putting the `document.ready()` in the head tag, then will it wait for the image to be downloaded or it will fire when all the HTML is downloaded?

In case it fires when all the HTML is downloaded, how do I avoid it?

How do I make the `.ready()` function fire after the 2.5MB data transfer?

Comment: Simple docs lookup would have answered this question. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: the simple docs have caused a little confusion and my question is not only about .ready(), its also about calling the .ready() function after the 2.5MB transfer is complete :)

Comment: @Rohan: `ready()` is not the right function for doing that, there's another function for that, namely, `load()`. Use the right tools for the right job - screwdrivers are for screws, hammers are for nails, they're not interchangeable; it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

Fire when the [DOM is loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (even if multimedia no loaded yet)

```
$(window).load(...)
```

Fire when all the [content is loaded](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (when the progress indicator which shows the loading process is gone)

Comment: and we should indicate here that  when we say that the 'DOM is loaded' we mean that first the html is parsed and rendered (only the html, without the resources being downloaded) and then the dom, based on the html, is created

Answer (score 3):

To quote [the documentation for `ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. [...] The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready [...]

So yes, it may fire *before* images are loaded (that's what it's for, after all). It even adresses this explicitly:

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

The documentation for `load()` is here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2):

As in the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the `load` event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed.

So it's when the `<img>` tags are loaded, but not the actual data of the images.

An example of loading the images and triggering an event when they are loaded:

```
<img data-src="images.jpg" />
<img data-src="images.jpg" />

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").load(function() {
    alert('image loaded');
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
  });
});
```

Comment: then what if I want it to fire when the actual 2.5MB image is downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside `$(document).ready()` will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents (html) are loaded.