# What javascript should put inside $(document).ready(function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does `$(document).ready(function() {` means all javascript file has been downloaded so any js init or func should work?

so it is a good practise to always put js inside `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {});` means your function run only if your documents already downloaded/ready. and depend if what function you make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is part of the page lifecycle and runs after all of the resources have been loaded for the page (HTML, CSS and JS files).

You should be functions in here that you need to run when the page first loads, so generally initialization of plugins, first run functions and attaching events to elements.

Any other functions that can run after the page has loaded can be defined outside of this scope.

Note that if you are dynamically inserting DOM elements, any events attached to that type or class (for example) will not be attached to them without re-attaching, or using `.on` and attaching to the document itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use ready() to make a function available after the document is loaded:
  for eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**Definition and Usage**
The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.

Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the example above.

The ready() method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.
note: The ready() method should not be used together with `<body onload="">.`

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery documentation:

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

It means that you can specify a function to run after the DOM is fully loaded, ie is available to interact with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Following is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133361/when-does-document-ready-actually-fire)

`$(document).ready(...)`

Fire when all DOM loaded (even if multimedia no loaded yet)

`$(window).load(...)`

Fire when all content loaded (progress indicator which shows loading proccess) gone.

---

Now here is my suggestion (not from that link)
I think the better approach would be putting your script tags at the end of body, like this, as it makes sure that the script is loaded when everything else has been loaded

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
bla bla bla
</div>
<script src="1"></script>
.
.
<script src="n"></script>
<script>console.log('hello');</script>
</body>
</html>
```