# Difference between passing a callback versus a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm curious, is there any difference between the two functions below?

Is one just passing a function inside an anonymous function when `ready` whereas the other is passing an actual named function when `ready`?

Example:

```
<p>Not loaded yet.</p>
```

First method:

```
function newName() {
  $( "p" ).text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.")
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  newName()
});
```

Second method:

```
function newName() {
  $( "p" ).text( "The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.")
}

$(document).ready(newName());
```

Is one more correct than the other?

Comment: In `$(document).ready(newName());` the `newName` function is ***not*** run when the DOM is loaded, it's ran *before*.  This is because you are running it immediately and passing its return value as the DOM ready handler.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is one just passing a function inside an anonymous function when `ready` whereas the other is passing an actual named function when `ready`?

Yes and no.

> I'm curious, is there any difference between the two?

The first is passing an callback function that is executed when the event fires. When that even fires is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8133361/5647260).

The latter passes the resolved return value (which is `undefined` because `newName` has no return statement), which isn't the same as the second. The reason it passes the return value to `ready` is because you invoke the function **immediately** (which may seem like it works), which then passes the return value. To make them *functionally* equivalent, do:

```
$(document).ready(newName);
```

This will pass a function *reference*, and won't invoke it. Also, as mentioned before, invoking as `ready(func(); func2();)` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks!  They asked because the former doesn't work but the latter did.  `$(document).ready(newName(); otherName(); otherName1());` is the one that worked oddly.

Comment: @JoshChristensen: I don't know where you saw that, but it's a syntax error.  You probably wanted `$(document).ready(function(){ newName(); otherName(); otherName1(); });`.

Comment: @JoshChristensen In the first you pass a callback, which executes on event trigger. The second, you *invoke* the function first (thus seemingly working), then you pass the return value of the function to `ready`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes this what the developer typed.  I know it isn't valid syntax but was explained that it worked.  Which I'm not sure how since the syntax isn't correct.

Comment: @JoshChristensen That's not valid syntax, and the first example should work. Not sure what they are telling you, but that's just incorrect

Comment: Agreed, I just debugged it myself and found it to be an issue with the actual function, the rest work.  Either way this has helped me with the difference between the 2 so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Effectively there’s no difference between

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  newName();
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(newName);
```

There’s a small technical difference: in the first snippet, an anonymous function calling `newName` is passed, in the second snippet, the named function `newName` *itself* is passed.

Functions are just callable objects that can be referenced by their name or the name of a variable holding the function.

Note that `$(document).ready(newName());` is calling `newName` — immediately — and passing the *return value* to `ready`. This only makes sense if `newName` returns another function, which in this case it doesn’t.

The title also mentions something like `$(document).ready(newName){}`. I’m assuming that’s a typo, since that’s not valid syntax.

`$(document).ready(newName(); otherName(); otherName1());` also isn’t valid syntax.